# Downloading github code

Tags: raspberry-pi, github

I found this article when trying search how to renew DNS on noip.

https://github.com/loblab/noip-renew

But i don't know how to use it.

I saw the usage as below: 
Code: Select all

> Usage Set your noip.com account info and number of hosts in
>   noip-renew.sh, Run setup.sh, Run noip-renew.sh, check result.png (if
>   succeeded) or error.png (if failed) For docker users, check
>   Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml, crontab-docker-host.
>
> Check confirmed records from multiple log files:
>
> ```
> grep -h Confirmed *.log | grep -v ": 0" | sort
> ```

1. download it as zip then extract
2. configure my account on no-ip in appropriate file ?

right ?

In case , if i would like to use docker , how to do it?

Comment: I find that `ddclient` does what I need for noip (and for dyn), it's already in the repo.  just install it and follow the examples in /usr/share/doc/ddclient

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this question should be on Stackoverflow, since it's really about how to follow instructions, albeit *linux commands* and the utility is designed to run on Linux, but not really a Linux question per se, apart from the understanding of what it does.

The instructions are outlined :

> 1. Set your noip.com account info and number of hosts in `noip-renew.sh`,
> 2. Run setup.sh,
> 3. Run `noip-renew.sh`, check result.png (if succeeded) or
>      error.png (if failed)

Here's more explanation.

1. Look at the page your URL takes you to, and download the zip of the project files, (see top right, Green button *Clone or Download*).
2. unzip the file and change directory to the extracted folder `noip-renew-master`.
3. edit the file named `noip-renew.sh` and change the relevant lines near the top of the file with your details.

Relevant lines :

```
USERNAME="change-the-username"
PASSWORD="change-the-password"
NUM_HOSTS=3 # make sure to change this to the number of configured dynamic hosts on your no-ip account
```

4. run the command `sudo ./setup.sh <your unix username>` This command will,

   - install `chromedriver`, `python-pip`
   - python-pip is then used to install selenium, which is used during the renew process. Selenium is used to drive the web-browser to press the correct buttons at the noip.com website.
   - It will update `/etc/crontab`  replacing lines with `noip-renew` with it's configured version, which runs the renew command 03:45 on Monday, Wednesday, and Friday every week of the year.
5. run the command `noip-renew.sh` and check for the output image files, view the image files to check that the renew command worked as expected.

There is no remove script!!. Read the setup.sh bash script and read the deploy() function you can read what it will do to your system. You should understand what it does so that you can de-configure it if you need to.